# What to put in the "Commit" button to insert data to the database? I am using stored procedure. C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

Good day everybody!

I am working on a school project and would like to ask for your expert assistance. Please accept my apologies in advance if this is something that is easy.

Program expectation:
    "Commit" button should insert data in the database using the stored procedure pre-set.

I have stored procedure that I will use to insert data in the database.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertPayroll]
@EmpID int,
@WeekEnding nchar(8),
@HoursWorked decimal(7,2)
AS
--*************************************************
--** Insert a new pay record into the Payroll table
--*************************************************
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @ErrCode int;

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Payroll] ([EmpID],[WeekEnding],[HoursWorked])
VALUES (@EmpID,@WeekEnding,@HoursWorked);

SET @ErrCode = @@ERROR;

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
RETURN @ErrCode;`
```

Then I have created a method from my global class:

```
public static DataSet InsertPayrollInfo(Int32 intEmpID, String strWeekEnd, Decimal decHoursWorked)
{
    SqlConnection cnSQL;
    SqlCommand cmdSQL;
    SqlDataAdapter daSQL;
    DataSet dsSQL = null;
    Boolean blnErrorOccured = false;

    cnSQL = AcquireConnection();
    if (cnSQL == null)
    {
        blnErrorOccured = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //**Build command to execute stored procedure
        cmdSQL = new SqlCommand();
        cmdSQL.Connection = cnSQL;
        cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdSQL.CommandText = "InsertPayroll";

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EmpID", SqlDbType.Int));
        cmdSQL.Parameters["@EmpID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmdSQL.Parameters["@EmpID"].Value = intEmpID;

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@WeekEnding", SqlDbType.NChar));
        cmdSQL.Parameters["@WeekEnding"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmdSQL.Parameters["@WeekEnding"].Value = strWeekEnd;

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HoursWorked", SqlDbType.Decimal));
        cmdSQL.Parameters["@HoursWorked"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmdSQL.Parameters["@HoursWorked"].Value = decHoursWorked;

        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ErrCode", SqlDbType.Int));
        cmdSQL.Parameters["@ErrCode"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        dsSQL = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            daSQL = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
            daSQL.Fill(dsSQL);
            daSQL.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            blnErrorOccured = true;
            dsSQL.Dispose();
        }
        finally
        {
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Clear();
            cmdSQL.Dispose();
            cnSQL.Close();
            cnSQL.Dispose();
        }
    }

    if (blnErrorOccured)
    {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return dsSQL;
    }
}
```

Now I was trying to use my commit button to insert data in the database using the stored procedure and class procedure. Below is my code.

```
private void btnCommit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (insertPayroll == null)
    {
        lblError.Text = "Error committing payroll information.";
        insertPayroll.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        for (Int32 i = 0; i < dtPay.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            insertPayroll = clsDataBase.InsertPayrollInfo(dtPay.Rows[i]["EmpID"]);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate any assistance and have a great evening!

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your question is. Is there something that is not working as expected? In that case, could you provide more information as to what error you get and at which point?

Comment: Hello there! Actually my question is, how do I code my btnCommit_Click to call my class to insert data in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class PayrollContext : IPayrollRepository
{
     public void InsertPayroll(params SqlParameter[] parameters)
     {
         using(var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
              using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
              {
                   connection.Open();
                   command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
                   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
              }
     }
}
```

Then to call the code to inserter into your database, you would simply do the following:

```
protected void btnCommit(object sender, EventArgs e) => new PayrollContext().InsertPayroll(new SqlParameter() 
{
     Name = "Hours",
     SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal,
     Value = txtHours.Text
}
```

Okay, let me explain the code.  The `IPayrollRepository`, `dbConnection`, and `query` are all items I didn't define.  The interface would be to abstract outward for reusability should you seek that need.  The two variables are pretty straight forward, you need to define a connection to the database and your query/stored procedure.

Then in your button event you build the class that access your database, you call the desired method, then you would pass all the parameters your supposed to insert into the database.

Now, I don't have null checks.  Including a null on your params.  Which are optional, so if nothing exists this code will explode.  As well as other particular data sanitizing checks.  But this should be a decent starting point.

Comment: Hello Greg, Thank you for the quick response. I will try that and let you know. :)